# Spring - Payment Gateway integration

Tags: spring, payment-gateway

I am trying to develop a proxy for a local payment gateway (i.e.: users will use our system to pay and the real payment gateway will be hidden). What is the best way to post calls to the payment gateway from our system? I was thinking of developing a service and use httpclient (post method over ssl) any ideas? or sample code?

the system could become complex coz I have transations and the http call would be part of them (call payment gateway, insert data locally, update some other records in db...etc..) and I was thinking of developing a special log to update it whenever any operation is successful if it is not I save it and process it later via cron ! is this a good architecture?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question is too subjective. What you've described is basically how *most* payment-related websites are built.

As for payment gateway, you can refer http://git.springsource.org/spring-payment/spring-payment/trees/master.

You can first create the basic design i.e. the DB structure and such. Once that's done, you can start developing with a stub. That'll help you validate your assumptions related to payment gateways. Once that's done, and everything's working fine, you can move on a real payment gateway.

In the meanwhile, you can visit payment gateway providers/Banks in person or online, and see which one works for you best. By the time you get the permission and all the formalities are in place, you'll hopefully have your system ready. You can then integrate your system with the real payment gateway.